# PHPMyAdmin CSV LOAD DATA affected rows not showing

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, load-data-infile, rows-affected

We are using PHPMyAdmin to do partial CSV imports (this is important as the lack of matching every column means we have to do CSV with LOAD DATA vs CSV import)

We try to keep up with the latest versions of PHP 5.6.22, PHPMyAdmin (on 4.6.3 now) and MySQL 5.5.46, and since around the mid PMA 4.5.x versions we lost the number of rows effected as part of the LOAD DATA import.

[Old behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfiye.png)

[No rows effected data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VowA9.png)

In the old behavior, there was a "# xx rows affected" in a single result window, but now there are two result windows, and then LOAD DATA query has nothing after the query. I would prefer to fix this to read as it did before.

I know the data is available somewhere, as a direct PHP/MySQL CSV LOAD DATA returns the data via mysqli_affected_rows, so I suspect PMA is my culprit. Is this a setting problem with updating from the versions I've had, or a bug to be reported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing revealed the PHPMyAdmin 4.6.0+ branch introduced this issue.

For me, I am dropping to 4.4/4.5 and reporting the issue to the developers [their GitHub issue page](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12345)